# I cannot visit one specific website on desktop, but on my phone it works. How do I fix this?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

When visiting the website em.com.br (sfw) I get an error:

```
"DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"
```

On my phone (which is using the same wifi) everything works.

OS: Ubuntu 17.10

Browser: FF 59.0.2, Chromium 65.0.3325.181

Traceroute:

```
    traceroute to em.com.br (200.188.178.56), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  fritz.box (192.168.178.1)  6.301 ms  6.308 ms  6.292 ms
 2  62.155.240.11 (62.155.240.11)  14.756 ms  14.758 ms  14.748 ms
 3  217.239.52.198 (217.239.52.198)  32.767 ms  32.762 ms  32.750 ms
 4  62.157.250.158 (62.157.250.158)  38.417 ms  38.416 ms  38.407 ms
 5  94.142.126.85 (94.142.126.85)  118.899 ms 213.140.35.198 (213.140.35.198)  124.067 ms 94.142.126.85 (94.142.126.85)  118.873 ms
 6  213.140.38.238 (213.140.38.238)  165.458 ms 176.52.251.66 (176.52.251.66)  146.426 ms 5.53.6.213 (5.53.6.213)  146.393 ms
 7  94.142.98.152 (94.142.98.152)  216.715 ms  216.006 ms 5.53.5.150 (5.53.5.150)  241.679 ms
 8  gvt-xe-6-1-9-4-grtriotw2.priv.net.telefonicaglobalsolutions.com (216.184.112.49)  246.134 ms 94.142.98.170 (94.142.98.170)  224.574 ms  234.436 ms
 9  gvt-0-0-2-4-grtssatw1.net.telefonicaglobalsolutions.com (216.184.112.131)  239.745 ms 152-255-128-247.user.vivozap.com.br (152.255.128.247)  252.448 ms  258.138 ms
10  152-255-128-245.user.vivozap.com.br (152.255.128.245)  263.563 ms  263.526 ms  258.044 ms
11  200.188.176.2 (200.188.176.2)  258.037 ms  261.028 ms estaminas.static.gvt.net.br (177.159.203.254)  260.990 ms
12  redir.estaminas.com.br (200.188.178.56)  263.435 ms !X  258.857 ms !X  268.570 ms !X
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because your phone is working on the same network doesn't mean all devices on the network are using the same DNS servers.   In your browser settings (or Internet Options) you can manually define the DNS server to use.  You can, for instance, use [OpenDNS](https://use.opendns.com/) to get around some traffic interception and throttling which has begun to occur in the wake of the USA's FCC reversal of Net Neutrality policies, as well as [Google's own DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), which are what your phone is probably using.  ISPs sometimes will direct your traffic to their own DNS servers or affiliated ones if you leave these set to "obtain automatically", which gives the ISP undue control over what you can and can't route to.  "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" means the DNS server used is either unable or unwilling to resolve the web address desired.

Comment: I changed the dns  on my router to openDNS, still get the same error

Comment: Change it on the PC.